# Report generation tool for WSS/foundation

Tags: web-services, office-integration

Rather then building our own tool from the ground up I am looking for a report generation tool for SharePoint, preferably WSS/Foundation.

I would like some kind of tool that will generate a Word report based on XML data from SharePoint lists and other sources (via web services).

I assume that such tools exists (otherwise it will be the very first time that I have come up with a brand new idea) but which one do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid i can get ban from administrator for this:) But take a look at [SharePoint Reports and Documents Generator](http://www.sharepointdrive.com) from my company Novitas. It allows you to generate reports using Word template and data from SharePoint lists.

Comment: @Mindaugas: This answer is fine as it is answers the question directly and you disclose your company.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options in this case as to what we use. We use SQL Reporting Services to generate reports, or we write custom reports with the Sharepoint object model. Reporting services gives you several export options but I do not believe that Word is a direct option. There is an RTF export option. Writing your own reports does give you a lot of flexibility as you can use .Net code to leverage both the Sharepoint object model and the Word object model.